# jQuery addClass and toggleClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I created a table using datatables and added a "More" button which triggers a mini-dropdown. This button and its dropdown content show perfectly, however, when I tried to distinctively show that the button is active anytime it is clicked using jQuery's `addClass()` or `toggleClass()` functions, the button refuses to add or toggle the "active" class.

`jQuery`

```
$( "#dropdownDatatableButton" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dropdownDatatableButton" ).addClass( "active" );
});
```

`CSS`

```
#datatablesDropdown .active {
    background: rgb(37, 56, 88) !important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

`datatables`

```
          { data: null,
        render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return '<div class="dropdown" id="datatablesDropdown">'

            + '<span class="material-icons btn datatables-more-btn" type="button" id="dropdownDatatableButton"' <!--here is the button that triggers the dropdown-->

            + 'data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">more_horiz</span>'
            + '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right datatables-dropdown-inner"'
            + ' aria-labelledby="dropdownDatatableButton">'
            + '<ul>'
            + '<li><a href="' + data.url.toLowerCase() + '/settings' + '">Board settings</a></li>'
            + '<li><a class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-left">Delete</a></li>'
            + '</ul>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>';
        },
    },
],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs must be unique in a page and you will also need to delegate the event listener since the plugin does re-renders for page changes, search, sort etc.

In addition you want to target the specific button the event occurred on

Try:

```
$('table').on('click', ".dropdownDatatableButton" ,function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
});
```

And change the ID to class in the html and css.

See: [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resource link. It sure gave me a better understanding of the subject. I followed through with your recommendation on the issue, that didn't solve it.

Comment: Make sure you didn't just change `id=` to `class=` since there already is a `class=` on those elements

Comment: Here is the modification made...

`'<span class="material-icons btn dropdownDatatableButton" id="dropdownDatatableButton"' + 'type="button"' + 'data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">'  + 'more_horiz</span>'`

Comment: Looks right. Do you have some material.js library perhaps also doing something with it?

Comment: No, I don't have that.

Comment: That worked! The problem was in my `jQuery` file. The `toggleClass` function was wrapped in a separate `$(document).ready(function(){ });` instead of putting it in the same one that wraps the table function. Thank you.